# How do I draw PDF NSData to a UIImage?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, pdf

I'm trying to basically understand how a simple PDF is created and turned into a UIImage on the iPhone. I have cobbled together this code:

```
NSMutableData *pdfData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, CGRectZero, nil);

CFAttributedStringRef currentText = CFAttributedStringCreate(NULL, (CFStringRef)@"Text", NULL);
CTFramesetterRef framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString(currentText);
UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, 612, 792), nil);
CGMutablePathRef framePath = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathAddRect(framePath, NULL, CGRectMake(0, 0, 612, 792));
CTFrameRef frame = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetter,
                                            CFRangeMake(0, [(NSString *)currentText length]),
                                            framePath,
                                            NULL);

CTFrameDraw(frame, UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
UIImage *pdfImage = [UIImage imageWithData:pdfData]
```

I am fairly certain that this code is correct, aside from the last line (which is incorrect because UIImage cannot read PDF data), so I'm trying to find out which class I can send my PDF into.

'pdfData' is not nil, it is about 5000 bytes in size.

Any help you guys can give will be much appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: Shouldn't the bounds passed to `UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData()` be something other than `CGRectZero`?

Comment: Giving CGRectZero to this function gives the context the default bounds of (0, 0, 612, 792).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use UIWebView to read pdf or DocumentPreviewController.

Comment: It works! UIWebView was right. I need to flip the coordinates to display the text correctly, but that's another story.

If anyone would like to know, this is the code I used to put my PDF in the webview, after I initialized it:

[pdfWebView loadData:pdfData MIMEType:@"application/pdf" textEncodingName:@"utf-8" baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]];